Unexpected behaviour of matmul when compiled with blas in Fortran
I am trying to benchmark the blas routines dgemv and dgemm in Fortran. For that I have written this simple codes:
matmul.f90:
program test                                                                                                                                                                                  
implicit none                                                                   
integer :: i, s                                                                 
real(8), allocatable :: a(:,:), b(:,:), c(:,:), x(:), y(:)                      
real(8) :: t1, t2                                                               
                                                                                
print *, "Matrix-Matrix multiplication"                                         
do i=1,9                                                                        
    s = 2**i                                                                    
    if (allocated(a)) deallocate(a)                                             
    if (allocated(b)) deallocate(b)                                             
    if (allocated(c)) deallocate(c)                                             
                                                                                
    allocate(a(s,s), b(s,s), c(s,s))                                            
                                                                                
    call random_number(a)                                                       
    call random_number(b)                                                       
                                                                                
    call cpu_time(t1)                                                           
    c = matmul(a, b)                                                            
    call cpu_time(t2)                                                           
    write(*,*) s, t2-t1                                                         
end do                                                                          
                                                                                
print *, "Matrix-vector multiplication"                                         
do i=1,9                                                                        
    s = 2**i                                                                    
    if (allocated(a)) deallocate(a)                                             
    if (allocated(x)) deallocate(x)                                             
    if (allocated(y)) deallocate(y)                                             
                                                                                
    allocate(a(s,s), x(s), y(s))                                                
                                                                                
    call random_number(a)                                                       
    call random_number(x)                                                       
                                                                                
    call cpu_time(t1)                                                           
    y = matmul(a, x)                                                            
    call cpu_time(t2)                                                           
    write(*,*) s, t2-t1                                                         
end do                                                                                                                                                                                    
end program

blas.f90:
program test                                                                                                                                                                                  
implicit none                                                                   
integer :: i, s                                                                 
real(8), allocatable :: a(:,:), b(:,:), c(:,:), x(:), y(:)                      
real(8) :: t1, t2                                                               
                                                                                
print *, "Matrix-Matrix multiplication"                                         
do i=1,9                                                                        
    s = 2**i                                                                    
    if (allocated(a)) deallocate(a)                                             
    if (allocated(b)) deallocate(b)                                             
    if (allocated(c)) deallocate(c)                                             
                                                                                
    allocate(a(s,s), b(s,s), c(s,s))                                            
                                                                                
    call random_number(a)                                                       
    call random_number(b)                                                       
                                                                                
    call cpu_time(t1)                                                           
    c = matmul(a, b)                                                            
    call cpu_time(t2)                                                           
    print *, s, t2-t1                                                           
end do                                                                          
                                                                                
print *, "Matrix-vector multiplication"                                         
do i=1,9                                                                        
    s = 2**i                                                                    
    if (allocated(a)) deallocate(a)                                             
    if (allocated(x)) deallocate(x)                                             
    if (allocated(y)) deallocate(y)                                             
                                                                                
    allocate(a(s,s), x(s), y(s))                                                
                                                                                
    call random_number(a)                                                       
    call random_number(x)                                                       
                                                                                
    call cpu_time(t1)                                                           
    call dgemv('n', s, s, 1.d0, a, s, x, 1, 0.d0, y, 1)                         
    call cpu_time(t2)                                                           
    print *, s, t2-t1                                                           
end do                                                                                                                                                                                    
end program

Note that in the blas program i am still using matmul and i have only changed the matrix-vector multiplication
I compile both codes with:
gfortran -o matmul matmul.f90
gfortran -o blas blas.f90 -lblas
I would expect the times of the matrix-matrix multiplication to be the same, but the results I get are (i write them side-by-side):
Matrix size     matmul.f90                    blas.f90
       2   4.0000000000000105E-005     1.7969999999999930E-003
       4   1.0999999999999725E-005     1.2780000000000014E-003
       8   2.3000000000000017E-005     8.0599999999997340E-004
      16   4.8000000000000299E-005     2.4819999999999842E-003
      32   1.1799999999999962E-004     5.3250000000000242E-003
      64   3.4200000000000029E-004     1.7175999999999969E-002
     128   1.2079999999999999E-003     5.3132000000000013E-002
     256   4.7889999999999999E-003    0.20821500000000004     
     512   1.2796999999999999E-002     1.1222690000000000  

Apparently the behavior of the matmul subroutine has changed in the second program and i am not really sure why. Could someone clarify this behavior to me?
Thanks!

Can you check the residuals c - matmul(a,b) to see which one given the incorrect result.

Are you aware of gfortran's  -fexternal-blas option?  It will map a few Fortran subprograms such as matmul to a BLAS routines.   There is also the -finline-matmul-limit=N option that controls the size of matrices/arrays for which gfortran will do inlining.

Could you double-check your timings? I tested your code (with gfortran 10 on Linux) and got pretty much the same timings for the matrix-matrix multiplication with the intrinsic matmul with or without -lblas

@PierU; I performed this test in three different computers. Two of them get almost the same timings with matmulor blasas you are finding. However, in the third computer where i was testing i keep getting the result i posted above. It is definitely something on my side and i will have to investigate what could have gone wrong... Thanks!
